# Unable to process multiple messages with async server socket

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

I have an async server socket (Based on the MSDN Example found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example)) that is good for 1 message. I am currently receiving 39 bytes of data which is the first message and it works great. However the server socket fails to receive messages 2 and 3. Here is my code

```
private void PrivateStartListening()
    {
        try
        {
            var socket = ManagementSocket.Socket;
            var localEndPoint = ManagementSocket.GetEndPoint();
            socket.Bind(localEndPoint);
            socket.Listen(100);
            Msg.Debug("Listening...");
            while (true)
            {
                // Set the event to nonsignaled state.  
                AllDone.Reset();

                socket.BeginAccept(
                    AcceptCallback,
                    socket);

                // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.  
                AllDone.WaitOne();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Msg.Debug(e.ToString());
        }

        Msg.Debug("read completed");

    }

    private void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult Ar)
    {
        // Signal the main thread to continue.  
        AllDone.Set();

        // Get the socket that handles the client request.  
        var listener = (Socket)Ar.AsyncState;
        var handler = listener.EndAccept(Ar);

        // Create the state object.  
        var state = new StateObject { WorkSocket = handler };
        handler.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, StateObject.BUFFER_SIZE, 0,
            ReadCallback, state);

    }

    private void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult Ar)
    {
        // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket  
        // from the asynchronous state object.  
        var state = (StateObject)Ar.AsyncState;
        var handler = state.WorkSocket;

        // Read data from the client socket.   
        var bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(Ar);

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            handler.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, StateObject.BUFFER_SIZE, 0,
                ReadCallback, state);
        }

        // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.  
        state.Sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
            state.Buffer, 0, bytesRead));

        // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read   
        // more data.  
        var content = state.Sb.ToString();

        // All the data has been read from the   
        // client. Display it on the console.  
        Msg.Debug($"Read {content.Length} bytes from socket. \n Data : {content}");
        var fields = content.TrimEnd('\r', '\n').Split(',').ToList();
        if (fields[1] == "0")
        {
            handler.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, StateObject.BUFFER_SIZE, 0,
                ReadCallback, state);
        }
        var paymentDetails = ProcessPaymentResponse(fields);
        if (paymentDetails != null)
        {
            ResponseQueue.Enqueue(paymentDetails);
            ResponseResetSignal.Set();
        }

        // Echo the data back to the client.  
        //Send(handler, content);

    }


    private static void Send(Socket Handler, string Data)
    {
        // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.  
        var byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Data);

        // Begin sending the data to the remote device.  
        Handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
            SendCallback, Handler);
    }

    private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult Ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.  
            var handler = (Socket)Ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.  
            var bytesSent = handler.EndSend(Ar);
            Msg.Debug($"Sent {bytesSent} bytes to client.");

            handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            handler.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }`
```

I have also attached the screen shot of what wireshark sees (so there is defiently multiple messages being sent)[image: Messages being recieved by wireshark but not asny server socket]

My Question is, how come i can receive the first message successfully but not the the ones immediately following/

I have spent all morning perusing the archives and i am still none the wiser. I do apologise if it also seems like a duplicate question. None of the previous answers have worked for me. Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your ReadCallback() reads only the first part of the data available, then exit. So, the only way to jump into ReadCallback() is to establish another connection: listener -> AcceptCallback -> ReadCallback

So, just try to modify ReadCallback into loop-based version that waits for new data until socket is closed by counterparty (or another event triggered to stop the loop, let say by user decision).

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I thought that the use of recursion would handle that? Im using the same socket and calling beginreceive which should get the second package?

Comment: Anyway, you should understand that BeginReceive would fall into a timeout if nothing has been sent for a while, and then to repeat BeginReceive process again and again.